# Filter numbers from an array calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm building a calculator and have the following array `['1','2','+','5','4']` from the input, I would like to filter out those numbers to `[12,'+',54]`.

How would I do it in javascript?

Here is what I tried, but this method only filter out the singular number and I would like the whole number.

Update: I would like to keep the operator also in the array. How would I fix the regex for that?

```
let numbers = [];
input.forEach(el => {
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(el) && !isFinite(parseFloat(el))){
        numbers.push(el);
    }
})
```

Comment: you should aggregate the consecutive characters that make a number (typically `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `.` and parse the aggregated string as a single number. You can update the code like this : ````let numbers = [];
    let currentNumber = "";
    input.forEach(el => {
        if(!isNaN(parseFloat(el)) && !isFinite(parseFloat(el))){
          currentNumber += e1
        }
        else {
          if (currentNumber)
            numbers.push(parseFloat(currentNumber))
        }
    })
    if (currentNumber)
            numbers.push(parseFloat(currentNumber));````

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` your array into a single string and then use RegEx to `split` on any non-numeric (`[^0-9]`) characters. Because the output will be strings, you'll need a `.map(n=>+n)` to convert them to integers.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '+', '5', '4', '-', '8'];
const result = arr.join('').split(/[^0-9]/).map(n => +n);
console.log(result);
```

> Update: I would like to keep the operator also in the array. How would I fix the regex for that?

Same as above, just wrap the regex in parens to form a capture group. You'll also want a conditional check for int (`+n || n`) as the array now has strings.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '+', '5', '4', '-', '8'];
const result = arr.join('').split(/([^0-9])/).map(n => +n || n);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your output is ["12","54"] which is string values, expected is numbers,

Answer (score 0):

The sample calc interpreter with any number of `+`, `-` operators have been converted into JS code from python given in the below link. You can modify it and build the remaining part.
It has currently

1. Handle `+` & `-` operator support.
2. Handle whitespaces in the input.
3. Handle any no of inputs etc `1+2+3-20 ...`
4. Handle multi digit inputs for example `22 + 35` or `200 +340` etc

What it doesn't have

1. Support for `*` & `/`

```js
const INTEGER = 'INTEGER'
const PLUS    = 'PLUS'
const MINUS   = 'MINUS'
const EOF     = 'EOF'

class Token {
  // class methods
  constructor(type, value) {
   // token type: INTEGER, PLUS, MINUS, or EOF
this.type = type
// token value: non-negative integer value, '+', '-', or None
this.value = value
  }
  tokenRep() {
   return {type: this.type, value: this.value}
  }
}
class Interpreter{
constructor(text) {
 // client string input, e.g. "3 + 5", "12 - 5", etc
    this.text = text
    //this.pos is an index into this.text
    this.pos = 0
    //current token instance
    this.current_token = ''
    this.current_char = this.text[this.pos]
}
error() {
 throw new Error('Error parsing input');
}
advance() {
 //Advance the 'pos' pointer and set the 'current_char' variable."""
    this.pos += 1
    if (this.pos > this.text.length - 1){
        this.current_char = ''  // Indicates end of input
    } else {
        this.current_char = this.text[this.pos]
    }
}
skip_whitespace() {
    while(this.current_char != '' && this.current_char == ' ') {

        this.advance()
    }
}
integer(){
 //Return a (multidigit) integer consumed from the input."""
    let result = ''
    while(this.current_char != '' && ! isNaN(this.current_char)){
     result += this.current_char
        this.advance()
    }
        
    return parseInt(result)
}
get_next_token(){

    //Lexical analyzer (also known as scanner or tokenizer)

   // This method is responsible for breaking a sentence
    //apart into tokens.
    //"""
    while( this.current_char !=  ''){
     if(this.current_char == ' '){
      this.skip_whitespace()
            continue
     }
            

        if(!isNaN(this.current_char)){
            return new Token(INTEGER, this.integer())
        }

        if(this.current_char == '+'){
         this.advance()
            return new Token(PLUS, '+')
        }
            

        if(this.current_char == '-'){
         this.advance()
            return new Token(MINUS, '-')
        }
           

        this.error()
    }
        

    return new Token(EOF, null)
   
}
eat(token_type) {
 // compare the current token type with the passed token
    // type and if they match then "eat" the current token
    // and assign the next token to the this.current_token,
    // otherwise raise an exception.
    if(this.current_token.type == token_type){
        this.current_token = this.get_next_token()
    }
    else{

        this.error()
    }
}
term() {
 //Return an INTEGER token value."""
    let token = this.current_token
    this.eat(INTEGER)
    return token.value
}
   
expr() {
 //Parser / Interpreter

 //expr -> INTEGER PLUS INTEGER
 //expr -> INTEGER MINUS INTEGER
 //
 // set current token to the first token taken from the input
 this.current_token = this.get_next_token()

 let result = this.term()
    while([PLUS, MINUS].includes(this.current_token.type)){
     let token = this.current_token
        if(token.type == PLUS){
         this.eat(PLUS)
            result = result + this.term()
        } else if (token.type == MINUS) {
         this.eat(MINUS)
            result = result - this.term()
        }
           
           
    }
        

    return result
}

     

}
let input = '12+ 54'
interpreter = new Interpreter(input)
result = interpreter.expr()
console.log(input + ' = ' +result)

input = '10+5-30'
interpreter = new Interpreter(input)
result = interpreter.expr()
console.log(input + ' = ' +result)
input = '12+54+600'
interpreter = new Interpreter(input)
result = interpreter.expr()
console.log(input + ' = ' +result)
```

> **I highly recommend reading this article if you would like to build a fully functional calculator interpreter. None of the array filtering
>   or parsing might not work, you need to create tokens and parse it
>   accordingly then only you can build a fully functional calculator
>   which can handle any kind of input.**

https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/

Comment: He probably asks for something a bit more generic that juste parsing this specific array... what about other operation, or numbers with decimal parts ?

Comment: Thats not dynamic. It will only add.

Comment: @JulienBarrois  updated the code with a sample parser.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `join` and use `match`

```js
let arr = ['1','2','+','5','4']

let giveMeDigits = (arr) =>{
  return arr.join('').match(/\d+/g).map(e=> +e)
}

console.log(giveMeDigits(arr))
```